# How to remove the gradient from a UIToolbar

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitoolbar

I want to make a table view that has translucent cells using the iOS7 translucency effect. To do this I'm setting the cell background to be a UIToolbar.

This works however it seems like the UIToolbar comes with a gradient which makes the cells look uneven.

[image]

Is there a way to remove this gradient and make the toolbar an even blur?